# Counting Enumeration Problem

Tags: combinatorics

Assume a set $N=\{1,\dots,n\}$. Let $A_n$ be the set of ordered pairs $(a,b)$ so that $b$ is a subset of $N$ and $a$ is a subset of $b$. Show that $|A_n|=k^n$ for a suitable $k$.

So far, I am thinking that if we take an element of $A_n$ then I make an $n$-length sequence where I go through $1$...$n$ and see how many times it occurs in either $a$ and $b$ of the element and write that sequence accordingly. E.g.In $A_6$, $(\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,3,4,5\})$ would correspond to the sequence $(2,2,2,1,1,0)$. With this approach I would need to figure out how to count how many elements are in the image of my bijection. Since this would be all sequences of $0,1,2$, it would be easy to count. I would guess that this is $3^n$. Am I on the right track or is there another approach that I should be taking? Please do not tell me the answer, I just want to know if my approach is valid.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear about your problem statement. Do you want $a$ and $b$ themselves to be ordered sets? In the example you give, $A$ is, but also in this case $|A_n|$ will not be $3^n$ (in fact it will be infinite, since elements of $A_6$ can apparently be infinitely long. Do you perhaps want $a$ and $b$ to be unordered subsets of $N$?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the post I meant ordered pair. I will change it now.

Comment: OK, but then your example is still wrong, or at least I don't understand it. Did you mean the ordered pair $(\{1,2,3\}, \{1,2,3,4,5\})$?

Comment: Yes. That is correct

Comment: Ah. Then your approach seems just fine, and you have shown that the number of sequences of length $n$ containing $2$, $1$, and $0$ is $3^n$ (well, you haven't exactly shown that, but you did assert it). What you *haven't* shown is that the map you've implicitly defined between pairs $(a,b)$ and sequences of length $n$ with elements chosen from $\{2,1,0\}$ is in fact a bijection.

Comment: Ok, and I can just do that by showing there is an inverse which shouldnt be too hard but thank you for verifying.

Comment: That's right. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

For each element *x* in *N* we have 3 ways -

1) *x* is not listed in both *a* and *b*

2) *x* is listed in *b* only

3) *x* is listed in both *a* and *b*

As there are *n* elements in *N* and each element has 3 choices, the answer is $3^n$.